# How can I link to a Markdown section of my Bitbucket README?

Tags: git, github, markdown, bitbucket

I'm trying to create a link to a section of the README file of my Bitbucket repository. The following works as expected on GitHub, but not on Bitbucket. What am I doing wrong?

```
## Navigation
[1. GIT To Work](#git)

... 

## 1. Git To Work - Working with git<a name="git"></a>
### What is git?
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for user support for a specific site; see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company .

Comment: Closing this question seems unfair. This [one about GitHub wikis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584788/change-font-in-github-flavored-markdown-for-table) remains open.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One peculiarity of Bitbucket's Markdown "flavour" is the way it names heading identifiers. If you inspect the HTML source of your Bitbucket README page (by default accessible at `https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<reponame>`), you'll see that the Markdown section

```markdown
## 1. Git To Work - Wording with git
```

translates to the following HTML heading element:

```html
<h2 id="markdown-header-1-git-to-work-working-with-git">1. Git To Work - Working with git</h2>
```

Note that Bitbucket uses, as the value of the `id` attribute, a URL-friendly version of your heading, prefixed by `markdown-header-`. Therefore, you can create a link to the corresponding section, in your Markdown code, using

```markdown
[Link to Git](#markdown-header-1-git-to-work-working-with-git)
```

Comment: My Bitbucket doesn't generate "id" attribute for headers. It's just simply "<h2>YAML configuration</h2>". How can I link to it? (Atlassian Bitbucket v5.8.0)

Comment: Our internal BitBucket does not auto generate ID's on h2's either.

Comment: Just used this answer to reach the probably more up-to-date solution - for me I used `[Link to Git](#markdown-header-git-to-work-working-with-git)` - prefixing with `markdown-header` (and not `markdown-header-1` or any number at all). Thanks!

Comment: On Bitbucket Server, there is neither a name or id generated on header tags and it will strip id attributes, so you're forced to use `name` and link to the name specified.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley My answer is getting old, now. Things might have changed. Feel free to update it or, better, post your own answer.

Comment: That's fair.  I was just adding nuance as I'm pretty sure Bitbucket Cloud works as your answer provides.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Can you please explain what you mean by "using `name`"? Maybe, as it seems to affect everyone using BitBucket Server, it would be even worth a separate answer?

Comment: Found answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67322161/985292 .

Comment: These `#` URI fragments don't work on Page load. They only work after the page has fully loaded. So if you copy & paste the full URL into a browser, it won't scroll to the right spot on page load. You can prove this by adding e.g. an extra "x" the the URL, press `enter`, then remove the "x" and press `enter`.  The 2nd `enter` will finally scroll to the right spot.

Answer (score 13):

Anchor links work on my Bitbucket server but don't work in VS Code unfortunately.

```
[link](#section) 

## Code and Syntax highlighting  <a name="section"></a>
```

Comment: Worked for me (BB 7.6.0) whereas the accepted answer didn't. This is also the accepted solution on the Atlassian support website: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Markdown-internal-links-support-in-Bitbucket-Server/qaq-p/595033

Comment: Thank you, the `<a name>` tag works on Bitbucket server. 
However, when placing it behind the header title, clicking the link will scroll to the line below the header (e.g. header title is not visible on page). To resolve this, move the anchor in front of the title, i.e. `## <a name="section"></a>Code and Syntax highlighting `

Comment: UPDATE: Although this was working in May 2021, it now doesn't work anymore. We needed to switch to using the prefix `#markdown-header-` based on the approved answer.

Comment: This worked for me as on 14/07/2022